# What is the best practice to generate positive and negative voltages to power an OpAmp

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-divider

I would like to supply +4.5V & -4.5V to OpAmp using a 9V battery. I have tried using [voltage divider](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-create-voltage-using-one-power-supply/) which works. 
Please suggest if this is the best practice, are there any better ways of doing this.

Note: Output current required is below 100mA.

Comment: Check the [Triadtron on this page](http://www.tubecad.com/2010/07/blog0189.htm) it should be able to source/sink about 20mA on the middle rail.

Comment: Whoops I meant the chapter called "Triadtron rail splitter".

Comment: @ Cornelius, Camil Staps, Ricardo, placeholder, and Leon Heller: The previous question you referred to referred to generating a low-current negative supply from an existing power supply, expressly for the negative rail of an  XR2206, which is quite different from splitting a supply for a fairly high current output in the way user44776 requested. Moreover, there was no mention of using switchers in the previous answers, so user 44776s's question elicited answers  which are unique, making his question valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can put an opamp buffer after your voltage divider for more current.
TI  makes a [rail splitter](http://www.ti.com/product/tle2426),  but I've never used it.

Answer (score 0):

"Best" is a judgement call and will depend on your application.  However, since you've stated that the output current required (ostensibly from the supplies) is in the vicinity of 100 mA, using a voltage divider will result in a lot of needless waste and meandering about the pseudo-ground.

If you want a stable ground and maximum life from your 9 volt battery, I suggest you use a couple of buck-boost regulators to get the + and - 4.5 volts you need. [Here](http://www.linear.com/parametric/Buck-Boost_Regulator#!1646_Buck-Boost%7CSEPIC!1032_%3C=4.5!1033_%3E=9!1105_%3C=4.5!1034_%3E=4.5!1035_0.332:3.32!1107_0.1:1!2086_%3E13.5!vinmin_4.5!vinmax_9!vout_4.5!iout_.1!vout2_!iout2_!vout3_!iout3_) are a few offerings from LTC, and [Here](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/power-management/buck-boost-converter-products.page) are a few from TI